# How to print a list of lists in a grid format?

Tags: python, list

If I have a list of lists like ([1,2,3,4,5],[2,4,6,8,10],[3,6,9,12,15])
How can I print it on the screen in a grid format? Just like:

```
1 2 3 4 5
2 4 6 8 10
3 6 9 12 15
```

My code is like

```
def print_table(listx):
    """returns a grid of a list of lists of numbers

    list of list -> grid"""
    for lists in listx:
        for i in lists:
            print(i,end='\t')
```

But I don't know how to make each list in a single row like example above.

Comment: `" ".join(i)` should work

Comment: @Udy agreed for "production" code, but probably this is from a course introducing control flow and variables so it's good to show how the sausage is made

Answer (score 2):

Maybe just adding an empty print on the main for:

```
def print_table(listx):
    """returns a grid of a list of lists of numbers

    list of list -> grid"""
    for lists in listx:
        for i in lists:
            print(i,end='\t')
        print()
```

Comment: I add print('\n') at the place that you do. But when I run it, there is a 'None' in my last row, just like 1,2,3,4,5 in row 1 and so on. And at the end row, there shows a 'None'. Why this shows out?

Comment: I added the '\n' in the print, and all it did was add a blank line between the printed numbers, the None didn't came up. How are you running this code?

Answer (score 0):

If the width of your elements varies more than tab width, you can use fixed width columns (filled by spaces):

```
>>> for x in listx:
...     for y in x:
...         print('{0:<10}'.format(y), end='')
...     print()
...
1         2         3         4         5
2         4         6         8         10
3         6         9         12        15
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution creates string with space-separated numbers in rows and `\n`-separated rows. It's using [str.center](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.center) method and generator-expressions.

> `str.center(width[, fillchar])`
>
> Return centered in a string of length width. Padding is done using the specified fillchar (default is an ASCII space). The original
>   string is returned if width is less than or equal to len(s).

```
def as_string(seq_of_rows):
    return '\n'.join(''.join(str(i).center(5) for i in row) for row in seq_of_rows)
l = ([1,2,3,4,5],[2,4,6,8,10],[3,6,9,12,15])
print as_string(l)
```

Output:

```
  1    2    3    4    5  
  2    4    6    8    10 
  3    6    9    12   15
```

Let's break it up:

```
str(i).center(5) for i in row
```

It iterates over row, converts values to strings and calls `center` method. Result is space-padded values.

```
''.join(sequence_above)
```

It creates single string from values. So now, string contains whole row.

```
'\n'.join(processed_row row in seq_of_rows)
```

It takes processed rows (strings)from previous step and joins them using newline character, so result is `row1\nron2\nrow3`.